# Restangular put() yielding a 404 when updating from a form

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, restangular

Restangular has been throwing me a 404 when sending PUT requests, and I'm not sure why.

I have an Events collection, and I'm getting a single event and updating it in a form.

According to the [Restangular docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), when I make a PUT request on the Event, it should route to `api/events/:eventId`. Instead, I'm getting an error saying it's routing to `api/events`.

The error:

```
PUT http://localhost:9000/api/events 404 (Not Found)
```

Can you see where I'm going wrong? I haven't changed the config on Restangular at all.

Here's my controller:

```
var restEvent = Restangular.one("api/events", $routeParams.eventId);

restEvent.get().then(function(eventData) {
  // the eventData is successfully coming through
  $scope.thisEvent = Restangular.copy(eventData);

  // $scope.thisEvent is modified in the form

  // updateEvent() runs when my Event form is submitted
  $scope.updateEvent = function() {
    $scope.thisEvent.put();
  };
});
```

Here's my Express update routes:

```
// update route -------------
app.route('/api/events/:event_id')
  .get(events.show)
  .put(events.updateEvent);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an issue with Restangular/Mongo. Restangular defaults its primary key to "id", whereas Mongo uses "_id". When Restangular tries to append "id" from the Event object to  `api/events`, it can't find "id" and only routes to `api/events`.

Here's the code that the [Restangular docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#i-use-mongo-and-the-id-of-the-elements-is-_id-not-id-as-the-default-therefore-requests-are-sent-to-undefined-routes) suggest, and that solves this issue:

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
      id: "_id"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be browser problem, I would recommend to go for this for PUT and PATCH:

```
  app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setMethodOverriders(['put', 'patch']);
  });
```

Comment: This didn't turn out to be the answer, but it pointed me in the right direction in the docs. Thanks!